# How to constrain solutions to be real-valued in Maxima CAS?

Tags: math, symbolic-math, maxima

I have found myself needing to solve complex-valued equations for two real-valued variables. In Mathematica, this is achievable using the `Assuming` command as follows:

[image: Mathematica goal]

I am interested to see if it is possible to use FOSS tools to achieve the same result. However, in Maxima, I have not found a way to constrain *a* and *b* to be purely real. It returns a complex-valued solution with one degree of freedom.

```
(%i22) solve(%e^(%i*%pi/4) = a*(%i*b+1), [a,b]);
                                  %i + 1
(%o22)             [[a = ------------------------, b = %r4]]
                         sqrt(2) %i %r4 + sqrt(2)
```

Even using `declare(a, real)` and `declare(b, real)` before running `solve`, it gives the same result. I have also tried to add constraints within the system of equations, but that doesn't work either:

```
(%i9) solve([x^3=1, imagpart(x)=0], x);
                           sqrt(3) %i - 1          sqrt(3) %i + 1
(%o9)       [[x = 1], [x = --------------], [x = - --------------]]
                                 2                       2
```

Is solving an equation like this possible in Maxima or any other FOSS CAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question. I asked Maxima guys using mailing list (yeah, it's still functioning) and they told me that `solve` ignores declares and this seems to be the easiest solution:

```
%e^(%i*%pi/4) = a*(%i*b+1)$
solve([realpart(%),imagpart(%)],[a,b]);
```